# console print some error when I deploy my blog to my website

Tags: vuepress

when I finished my vuepress blog and deploy to my website. chrome console always print out the following error message . it's doesn't seem to affect function. but I want to fix it . how can I do ?

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTZJi.png)

Comment: Please add error message as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Do you trying remove a node of DOM manually?

i.e. `document.getElementById("any-element").removeChild("other-element");`

You shoudn't to do this, because the Vue is resposible for handling DOM.

But if you need do something like that, you must to verify if the `window` object exist. Because when you build the Vuepress site, Node.js do a prerender of all HTML files and in this context the `window` object doesn't exist.